# How to get all users that have each of these tags?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-and-belongs-to-many

```
User has_and_belongs_to_many tags
Tag has_and_belongs_to_many users
```

I'm looking for a way to get every user that has tags `2` and `5` with one query, preferably built using activerecord.

I know I could do this

```
users1 = Tag.find(2).users
users2 = Tag.find(5).users
usersFinal = users1 & users2
```

But I want to get the list of users and merge them with SQL to prevent merging arrays in ruby.

**EDIT**: I'm using mysql2

Comment: what is the DB engine you are using ?

Comment: mysql2 - updated in the question

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [map](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/map) method:

```
Tag.find([2,5]).map(&:users)
```

---

Edit2

You can also use *includes*:

```
User.includes(:tags).where(tags: { id: [2,5] })
```

Comment: This seems to return an array of two ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy
unmerged. 
It takes 3 queries, which is better than my provided 4, but still leaves the intersection up to ruby. Is there a way to intersect the 2 user groups in sql?

Comment: hehe  that's easy.. why I thought so long trying to think :/

Comment: In response to your edit:
User doesn't have a tag_id column.
I suspect you mean to use 
`User.joins(:tags).where('tags.id IN (2, 5)')`
Or some form that does an intersection instead of a OR like I did here. 
What would be the intersection version of this query?

Comment: The query you've written above does look correct. I've tested with my local data and it works.

Comment: It works, but it doesn't do what I want. It get all users with _either_ tag.
I want all users with _both_ tags.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have `user_tags` table to support your many-to-many relationship, I would do it with the following `SQL`:

```
SELECT users.id, COUNT(user_tags.tag_id) as tags_count 
FROM users
JOIN user_tags ON users.id = user_tags.user_id
WHERE user_tags.tag_id IN (2,5)
GROUP BY users.id
HAVING COUNT(user_tags.tag_id) > 1;
```

Here we select `users` with any of given tags (eighter `2` or `5`), group rows so that each row represents a single user, and check count of "nested" rows (which equals to count of references to the particular user in `user_tags` table). Assuming you have uniqueness validation which guarantees that there is only a single row for a pair of `user` and `tag`, user with both of them is the one who have more than 1 row "nested" (`having COUNT(*) > 1`).

Sorry for not being able to test it by myself, hope that gives you the insight. Refer to [HAVING (SQL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Having_%28SQL%29) function definition.